# Broke Okular by deleting all files manually

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, kde, okular

I manually deleted all files related to Okular (pdf viewer) and reinstalled it as there was a bug that purging and re-installing wouldn't solve. It now doesn't work and throws the error:

```
Unable to find the Okular component.
```

On the first attempt at running the terminal also outputs the error

```
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
kbuildsycoca4 running...
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
```

However, this only occurs initially.

I am running Kubuntu 16.04 and it's a relatively fresh install.

I think I need to re-download some program file relating to Okular but I'm not sure where or how to do this. I have tried using

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install --reinstall okular
sudo apt-get purge okular
```

and then reinstalling. I also tried updating packages just in case.

---

#### Edit

I first uninstalled okular by using the command

```
sudo apt-get purge okular
```

I then used the command

```
sudo find / -name "*okular*" | xargs rm
```

---

#### Edit 2

the command

```
dpkg -S 'okular' | awk -F: '!a[$1]++ {print $1}'
```

outputs this info:

```
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'libokularcore7'     missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
okular-extra-backends
okular-backend-odp
okular
okular-dev
kde-l10n-engb
libsmokeokular3
kubuntu-settings-desktop
calligra-l10n-engb
breeze-icon-theme
libokular-perl
```

Comment: +1 for hilarious :) What files did you delete and how did you do it? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/961687/edit) your question and add this information.

Comment: Please try `sudo apt install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop`, it won't hurt.

Comment: You might want to try something like `dpkg -S 'okular' | awk -F: '!a[$1]++ {print $1}'` to obtain a list of all the packages that think they should have files matching those that you deleted

Comment: Sorry I've just tried those suggestions and they didn't seem to work. I also tried reinstalling all the dependent packages the > dpkg -S 'okular' | awk -F: '!a[$1]++ {print $1}' outputted

Comment: Actually reinstalling libokularcore7 seems to have done it! Okular now works. Thank you!

Comment: Please add an answer with the solution below and accept it by clicking the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the dependencies was broken. I think it was the libokularcore7 one.

After following the step @steeldriver mentioned in the comment section i.e. using the command:

```
sudo dpkg -S 'okular' | awk -F: '!a[$1]++ {print $1}'
```

I was able to reinstall all the dependencies using:

```
for i in $(sudo dpkg -S 'okular' | awk -F: '!a[$1]++ {print $1}');
do sudo apt-get install --reinstall $i;
done
```

and then separately reinstall the libokularcore7 using the commmand

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libokularcore7
```

Comment: Please accept your answer by clicking the tick on the left.